# Android app - Facebook SDK login from PHP rest webservice

Tags: php, android, facebook, web-services, rest

I am developing an android application. In that I am using the Facebook SDK to share the messages and photos.

Facebook login and sharing is working fine in all devices except the HTC device. I have search over the internet about this issue. But I didn't get any solution.

So I am planning to use PHP rest web service to facebook login and sharing. (i.e) Get the facebook credentials from my android app and pass it into the PHP rest web service to get login. And same way to share photo in facebook.

Is it possible to do that?

If yes, Can you give some samples to do that?

If No, What difficulties I will face?